# Allow other base class to implement a virtual function

Tags: c++, c++11, multiple-inheritance

Is it possible to do the following:
My base class has 3 pure virtual functions. My derived class implements 2 of these virtual functions and inherits from another class that implements the final 3rd virtual function.

My current code won't compile so I am thinking this is not valid? Although it would be great if I could somehow use this approach. Below is my practical application/use of this approach.

Any suggestions of a different approach I could use to achieve this functionality?

```
class ListBox
{
public:
    virtual void onScroll() = 0;
    virtual void foo() = 0;
    virtual void bar() = 0;
};

class DragScrollHandler
{
public:
    void onScroll()
    {
        ...
    }
};

class HorzListBox: public ListBox, public DragScrollHandler // could also do public HoverScrollHandler, etc.
{
public:
    void foo() override
    {
        printf("foo\n");
    }

    void bar() override
    {
        printf("foo\n");
    }

    HorzListBox()
        : ListBox(), DragScrollHandler()
    {

    }
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ListBox` and `DragScrollHandler` are *a priori* different concepts, so there is no kind of link across the multiple inheritance. I mean it is not automatic to set a link in between the virtual `onScroll` inherited in some way, and an implementation of `onScroll` on another unrelated (to the other) branch.

You can define it on `HorzListBox` to call the inherited implementation:

```
void onScroll() override {
   DragScrollHandler::onScroll();
}
```

This would fulfill the contract: implement the abstraction and use the inherited implementation.

But may be the best way (in your case) is to separate concepts and have a `Scrollable`:

```
class Scrollable {
public: 
  virtual void onScroll()=0;
};

class ListBox: virtual public Scrollable {
public:
  virtual void foo()=0;
};

class DragScrollHandler: virtual public Scrollable {
public:
  void onScroll() override {...}
};

class HorzListBox: public ListBox, public DragScrollHandler {
public:
  void foo() override {...}
};
```

Answer (score 2):

> Any suggestions of a different approach I could use to achieve this functionality?

Make the derived class implementation a pass through to the other base class implementation.

```
class HorzListBox: public ListBox, public DragScrollHandler
{
public:
    void foo() override
    {
        printf("foo\n");
    }

    void bar() override
    {
        printf("foo\n");
    }

    void onScroll() override
    {
       DragScrollHandler::onScroll();
    }

    HorzListBox()
        : ListBox(), DragScrollHandler()
    {

    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

> Any suggestions of a different approach I could use to achieve this functionality?

For the sake of curiosity, you could use a *mixin* based approach like the following one:

```
struct ListBox {
    virtual ~ListBox() { }
    virtual void onScroll() = 0;
    virtual void foo() = 0;
    virtual void bar() = 0;
};

template<typename T>
struct DragScrollHandler: T {
    void onScroll() override { }
};

template<typename T>
struct HorzListBox: T {
    void foo() override { }
    void bar() override { }
};

int main() {
    ListBox *lb = new HorzListBox<DragScrollHandler<ListBox>>{};
}
```

Answer (score -3):

> My current code won't compile so I am thinking this is not valid?

Of-course it won't compile! Dervied class which don't override all pure virtual functions of an abstract base class, in turn also become an abstract class themselves. Which mean the Derived class can't be instantiated, hence the compile time error.

So in your case, Class HorzListBox is an abstract class as well since it doesn't override all PVFs of class ListBox.

Please rethink on these lines and modify your code accordingly.